# how to put widgets inside a PyQt QMdiSubWindow

Tags: python, pyqt4

Sorry, my question may sound very stupid but Frankly i spend a lot of time on internet trying to figure out how to add a widget**s** to QMdiSubWindow, I mean a **Multiple Widgets** not just one Widget(this is very important for me .. I need my Sub window to contain a multiple widget not a single widget).

for example i want to add this widgets and layouts to My Sub Window:

QVbox which contains a QlineEdit and Push Button, And QHbox which contain a a Push Button ...

> it doesn't matter if you show me how i could do it using the above example, what really matter is to show me how no matter what example you use

**Note** : Please Use OOP and Python not c++

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try adding a generic instance of `QWidget` to the `QMdiSubWindow`, then adding a layout to that generic `QWidget` then and putting all of your other widgets inside that layout?

Comment: I am not sure that I am following you ??

Comment: in that case, I've explained in more detail in the answer below. I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hierarchy of widgets and layouts should always follow

```
widget -> layout -> widget -> layout -> widget -> ...
```

where each widget can only have one layout, but each layout can contain multiple widgets (note that for simplicity the above only shows one widget per layout).

So, what you need to do is create a widget which contains a layout, and that layout contains the `QPushButton and`QLineEdit`. For example:

```
# construct the top level widget
widget = QWidget()
# construct the top level layout
layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)

# create the widgets to add to the layout
button = QPushButton('My Button')
lineedit = QLineEdit()

# add the widgets to the layout
layout.addWidget(button)
layout.addWidget(lineedit)

# set the layout on the widget
widget.setLayout(layout)
# we now have a single widget that contains a layout and 2 widgets
```

This allows you to effectively encapsulate multiple widgets inside a single widget (and is how a lot of the more complex Qt widgets are created internally, for instance the `QSpinBox`). So if you want another complex widget inside the layout above, you could again make another `widget2 = QWidget()`, create a layout (for instance `layout2 = QHBoxLayout(widget2)`), and then add multiple widgets to it. Once done, add the `widget2` widget to the original layout (`layout.addWidget(widget2)`).

Hopefully you can now see how to construct a single complex widget from an arbitrary number of child widgets and layouts.

At this point you can now set the single widget to an existing `QMdiSubWIndow`

```
# now add this widget to the QMdiSubWindow
mdisubwindow.setWidget(widget)
```

or alternatively, call the convenience function on the `QMdiArea` to create a new `QMdiSubWindow` with the widget:

```
mdisubwindow = mdiarea.addSubWindow(widget)
```

Note: For your specific example, you don't actually need to construct `widget2` to encapsulate the `QHBoxLayout`. You can add a `QHBoxLayout` (`layout2` in my rough example above) directly to the original layout by calling `layout.addLayout(layout2)`. However, this is more of a special case, and the general principle of encapsulation above of alternating widgets and layouts is more generalisable once you start making your own widget classes in order to re-use code.

Comment: Thanks so mush that worked very well, from your code my issue was that I am trying to add addLayout instead of addWidget

Comment: But a layout can also contain other layouts. No need to put a widget between. (QLayout is a QWidget too)